# After edit record in datatable, only first entry from backend is displayed using react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have edit/delete functionality for records. when I come on actual page, it displays all data but when I actually edit/delete. Only first entry from cloudant is displayed. But if I again click on edit/delete functionality it displays all data. Must be issue with react state.

Adding details about my implementation.
state:
[state in useEffect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fbTU.png)
I used Carbon components DataTable for rendering countryDetList data.
After edit/delete and Modal closing, only 1st record is displayed.

Comment: We need to know how you are implementing your business logic in order to help you!!
Please us more details about your code

Answer (score 0):

Becuase the state is not re-rendering

Check what are you setting in state
if you are using objects in state check how you are setting them
for example

```
  const [User,SetUser] = React.useState({})
    
    SetUser({id:21})
    
    this might not be cause a re-render
    SetUser({id:26})
    
    you can make it like
    
    SetUser({...{},...{id:26

}})
```